# QImage \ QPixmap loses alpha color when drawing

Tags: qt, png, alpha, qpainter, qimage

I have a PNG image with `QImage::Format_ARGB32` filled with color `ARGB(0, 255, 255, 255)`.

When I draw the image to another image with same format, color of alpha pixels loses. All `ARGB(0, 255, 255, 255)` pixels converts to `ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Following code loses color of alpha-pixels:

```
QImage sourceImage("image.png");
QImage destImage(sourceImage.width(), sourceImage.height(), sourceImage.format());
QPainter painter(&destImage);

painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
painter.drawImage(0, 0, sourceImage);
painter.end();
```

Scaling image loses color of alpha-pixels too:

```
QImage destImage = sourceImage:scaled(sourceImage.width() / 2, sourceImage.height() / 2);
```

But following code save pixels color:

```
QImage sourceImage("image.png");
QImage destImage(sourceImage.width(), sourceImage.height(), sourceImage.format());
for(int x = 0; x < sourceImage.width(); x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < sourceImage.height(); y++)
    {
        destImage.setPixelColor(x, y, sourceImage.pixelColor(x, y));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know workaround?
Qt 5.7, OSX

Comment: What is the problem with *losing* the color when it is fully transparent (alpha value = 0)? What is the exact problem you get as a result of that? What are you aiming for? Do you just want to paint the `QImage` on top of another `QImage`?

Comment: It's synthetic example. In real task I have image with white text rendering in OpenGL application. In that case I get black pixels artifacts around my white text because GL can mix color of pixel with neighbor pixels.